# シェルスクリプトの複数行実行

Tags: python

お世話になります
python内から、Linuxのシェルコマンドを複数行連続して実行するにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/bin
の後に、引数を伴うアプリを実行したいのですが、スペースで区切って１行に書いてみてもうまく実行されないようです

Answer (score 2, accepted):

セミコロンで区切れば連続で実行されます。

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import commands
check = commands.getoutput("export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/bin; echo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}");
print check
```

実行結果

```
$ ./test.py
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/bin
```

また、単にコマンドに環境変数を渡したいのであれば `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/bin command option ...` としても良いと思います。